# Rapid number updates on a website

Tags: c#, python, asp.net, web-services, perl

I wonder how to update fast numbers on a website.

I have a machine that generates a lot of output, and I need to show it on line. However my problem is the update frequency is high, and therefore I am not sure how to handle it.

It would be nice to show the last N numbers, say ten. The numbers are updated at 30Hz. That might be too much for the human eye, but the human eye is only for control here.

I wonder how to do this. A page reload would keep the browser continuously loading a page, and for a web page something more then just these numbers would need to be shown.

I might generate a raw web engine that writes the number to a page over a specific IP address and port number, but even then I wonder whether this page reloading would be too slow, giving a strange experience to the users.

How should I deal with such an extreme update rate of data on a website? Usually websites are not like that.

In the tags for this question I named the languages that I understand. In the end I will probably write in C#.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: What do you mean by *the human eye is only for control here*? Are you expecting this to be a data channel for remote software?

Answer (score 2):

a) WebSockets in conjuction with ajax to update only parts of the site would work, disadvantage: the clients infrastructure (proxies) must support those (which is currently not the case 99% of time).

b) With existing infrastructure the approach is Long Polling. You make an XmlHttpRequest using javascript. In case no data is present, the request is blocked on server side for say 5 to 10 seconds. In case data is avaiable, you immediately answer the request. The client then immediately sends a new request. I managed to get >500 updates per second using java client connecting via proxy, http to a webserver (real time stock data displayed).
You need to bundle several updates with each request in order to get enough throughput.

Comment: hm i think i like your b) answer however i am not familiar with it how does one make that with javascript ?, do you know of a example perhaps

Comment: I used java as client. With javascript you need to use asynchronous requests (XMLHttpRequest). If the request contains data, you render it, else you immediately resend a new request. The real work is on server side, i don't know about C# servers, with java you can use comet, or do a handcrafted solution (block calling thread if no data is avaiable for current client request). Maybe search for javascript-comet clients to get an idea.

Comment: Oh with a C# server, i ment that i can write a basic webserver in c#
But it doesnt come with the extra's of having a real webserver.

So i guess you basicly create a onpageload script that keeps updating a DIV section, like they do it in ajax ?.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a page reload. You can use WebSockets to establish an open two-way communication between a browser (via JavaScript) and your server.

Python Tornado has [support](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/websocket.html) for this built-in. Additionally, there are a couple of other Python servers that support it. [`Socket.IO`](http://socket.io/) is a great JavaScript library, with fallback, to facilitate the client side.

Comment: ok i will look into that i didnt want page reloads, websockets is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

On the backend you can use Redis or a NewSQL database like VoltDB for fast in-memory database updates. Caching helps a lot with high latency components (esp. in a write heavy application).

On the front-end you can look into websockets and the Comet web application model http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

Many gaming companies have to deal with fast counter updates and displays - it might be worth looking into. Zynga uses a protocol call AMF http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/3/10/how-farmville-scales-the-follow-up.html